# Edge target arrows not working in Cytoscape.js >=2.7.0

Tags: cytoscape.js

I noticed that edge source or target arrows are missing when using the current unstable branch (2.7.0-unstable). The standard cy demo show below. Is this a known issue or has something changed?

Comment: !(https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/5722945/16018601/23d6d1a2-3173-11e6-9bbc-2b2d9c3bcd28.png)

Answer (score 40):

[The default stylesheet was updated in 2.7](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/1199) to have greater performance by default.  This means that [haystack edges](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/haystack-edges) are used by default, and haystacks support only mid arrows.

If you set your edges in your stylesheet to beziers, then you can use source and target arrows, e.g.

```
edge {
  curve-style: bezier;
  target-arrow-shape: triangle;
}
```

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot.  I am currently using Cytoscape.js >=2.7.0 for network virtualization.

Comment: How do you set your edges in your stylesheet to beziers?

Comment: `style: { 'curve-style': 'bezier', /* ... */ }`

Answer (score 1):

Use like this.

```
cy.edges('edge').style({
    "curve-style": "bezier",
    "target-arrow-shape": "triangle"
})
```